# How do i save MPMediaItemCollection to NSUSerDefaults?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, mpmediaitemcollection

Anybody know how to do this? The standard method will not work. I want the user to pick a song, and then have it save for the next time they load the app, but i can't seem to get it into NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate the collection to get the MPMediaItems.
`MPMediaItem` inherits from `MPMediaEntity`, which has a `-valueForProperty:` method.  If you pass that method the `MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID` constant, you'll get back an `NSNumber` that uniquely identifies the item.  This is a value that's persistable across launches.

Comment: Hey Dave, I'm getting back null when I ask for the MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID on my MPMediaItemCollection using valueForProperty. I get back "0" if I use valueForKey. Any ideas?

Comment: @MakingScienceFictionFact MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID is only for MPMediaItems as the name suggests, not MPMediaItemCollections